BulkInsertOrUpdate causes MariaDB exception
I try to bulk merge into database table like this:
public async Task UpdateCitiesAsync()
{
    var request = new
    {
        apiKey = _apiKey,
        modelName = "AddressGeneral",
        calledMethod = "getCities"
    };

    string result = await ApiRequest(request);

    var cityResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NovaPoshtaResponse<City>>(result);

    await _context.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync(cityResponse.Data);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

but receive this exception:
MySqlConnector.MySqlException: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '0 T.[Ref], T.[Description] INTO [CitiesTempdada41e4] FROM [Cities] AS T LEFT ...' at line 1"

Above code worked right before I decided to change AddRange to bulk extension method.
BulkExtensions version is 6.0.2.

??? You use MariaDB but I see the syntax which is specific for SQL Server (MS SQL). Check does SET SQL_MODE="MSSQL"; is set. Also - a substring .. 0 T.[Ref] .. in the output list of SELECT part of the query is synthactically wrong anycase. Check result and cityResponse  values.

I use Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql to establish connection. Code worked just fine and was updating tables when I used AddRange and RemoveRange in this method, but broke after i change it to BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync.

@dellancelod, because you use third-party extension. Read this extension documentation, probably they do not support this DB Engine.

There's no BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync in EF Core. There's no "bulk update" in general, in the sense of the minimally logged, fast operations performed by BULK INSERT on SQL Server or COPY in MySQL. That third party extension doesn't do what it says

Let's see the generated SQL statement.

There's no BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync in EF Core. There's no "bulk update" in the sense of the fast, minimally logged BULK INSERT in SQL Server or COPY in MySQL and MariaDB. That third party extension doesn't do what it claims.
Since you're already using MySqlConnector you can use the MySqlBulkCopy class to execute a COPY from the client side :
var dataTable = GetDataTableFromExternalSource();

// open the connection
using var connection = new MySqlConnection("...;AllowLoadLocalInfile=True");
await connection.OpenAsync();

// bulk copy the data
var bulkCopy = new MySqlBulkCopy(connection);
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "some_table_name";
var result = await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(dataTable);

You can control what happens in case of conflict by setting the ConflictOption property, eg :
var bulkCopy = new MySqlBulkCopy(connection);
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "some_table_name";
bulkCopy.ConflictOption=MySqlBulkLoaderConflictOption.Replace;
var result = await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(dataTable);

What the extension actually does, is a classic ETL technique. It stores the data using SqlBulkCopy into a temporary table it creates silently, then first UPDATEing the target with an INNER JOIN
UPDATE TARGET
SET
   ...
FROM tempTable INNER JOIN Target on tempTable.ID=Target.ID

Followed by an INSERT using a LEFT JOIN to only pick new rows
INSERT INTO Target (...)
SELECT ....
FROM tempTable LEFT Join Target on tempTable.ID=Target.ID
Where Target.ID is NULL

While that may seem convenient, it gives you no control over the location or indexing of the staging table, join keys, filter conditions or transformations a script would give you.
